# How can I get WebDev on Magnolia admin central

Tags: magnolia

I only get Tools & MTE on my admin central, How can I get WebDev & Dev buttons as well.

I have setup magnolia with Empty web app and included Travel Demo.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the Site module to get the WebDev.

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Site+module